# how can i take the value outside of constant declared inside block

Tags: javascript, html, function

in the below code ...i need to take the value of ...rate.. outside and have to do further calculation with some other output coming from other code blocks

```
let price=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
price.forEach(radio => {
     radio.addEventListener('click',()=> {
      if(radio.checked){
         const rate= radio.value;
        console.log(rate);
        
      }
     }) 
});

const test=rate+4;
console.log(test);
```

am getting an error....test is not defines...so what i have to do.....am very new to javascripr

Answer (score 3):

you want to access `test` which change based on some event like `click` so put the change logic inside a function and call this function inside the `listener`

```js
let totalRate = 0;

function updateTest(newRate){
  totalRate += newRate;
}

price.forEach(radio => {
     radio.addEventListener('click',()=> {
      if(radio.checked){
         const rate= radio.value;
         updateTest(rate);
        
      }
     }) 
});
```